How do I enter a tiny vertical space above the first row in a table?
Consider the following MRE where you would notice that it's difficult for the average reader to see the bars above Q and k.
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
    cell 1 & cell2 \\ \hline
    $\bar{k}$ & $\bar{Q}$ \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}


How do I fix this issue? I don't really mind whether you insert a vertical space above the letters or use a more clever way -- I'm simply looking for a solution to this issue without having to write a lot of code (so that I can remember it and reproduce later when needed).

Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Remove the vertical lines and use \toprule, \midrule and \bottomrule of package booktabs instead of hline for better formatting of tabulars.

You wouldn't have this problem with tabularray, it has better spacing by default: https://i.sstatic.net/82cK18HT.png

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Made the necessary changes, it wasn't tedious at all. (I didn't require any package.)

@user326459 Great to hear it wasn't tedious, then it won't be a problem to directly include a MWE in all your future questions!

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Indeed. :)

While it's (of course!) ok to immediately upvote useful answers, site guidelines strongly encourage waiting several hours at least, and maybe even a day or two, before "accepting" any particular answer. That way, you don't discourage other would-be answer providers from posting additional, and possibly even better, answers.

You could use the tabularray package. It has a less crowed spacing by default and thus avoids the problem:
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{|c|c|}
\hline
    cell 1 & cell2 \\ \hline
    $\bar{k}$ & $\bar{Q}$ \\ \hline
\end{tblr}

\end{document}



Works like a charm! Thank you. (Note: I'll accept your answer once the site lets me, which is in about 7 minutes apparently.)

@user326459 Before you accept, please consider the comment by cabohah. Redesigning your table would make it look much more professional.

I did. The spacing is improved and the thickened borders look better.

I can think of two main solution methods. The first treats the symptom (by inserting a suitable typographic strut), while the second fixes the underlying problem (caused by non-existent vertical spacing adjustments around \hline directives). The second solution also provides a more open "look" by getting rid of the unneeded vertical lines.

\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs} % for \toprule, \midrule, and \bottomrule macros

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|}
    \hline
    header 1 & header 2 \\ \hline
    $\bar{k}$ & $\bar{Q}$ \\ 
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\quad 
% fix 1: treat the symptom
\begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|}
    \hline
    header 1 & header 2 \\
    \hline
    $\bar{k}$ & $\bar{Q}^{\strut}$ \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\quad 
% fix 2: treat the underlying problem
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{} cc @{}}
    \toprule
    header 1 & header 2 \\ 
    \midrule
    $\bar{k}$ & $\bar{Q}$ \\ 
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}

